# Shifted by negative number in java

Tags: java, bit-shift

I have problem with shift operator in Java.I have used following code and not unable to understand how this program generates this output.So please guide me how this program generates this output.

```
public class Operator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int s = 8;
        s = s >>-63;
        System.out.println("value of i=" + s);
    }

}
```

**Output:**
value of i=4

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the JLS, [section 15.19 (Shift Operators)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19):

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is int, only the five lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value 0x1f (0b11111). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range 0 to 31, inclusive.

Now `-63 & 0x1f == 1`, So this is actually a shift by 1 to the right, hence the answer of 4.

Comment: thanks for reply Jon but can you tell me, how can we recognize that this has to be shift bye one or two etc .So please guide me in this regard.

Comment: @Dipu: What do you mean by "recognize that this has to be shift bye one or two"? Your question is very unclear - you haven't told us anything about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: See jon I wanna know how can we know that -63 means sift by one .So there might be techniques.i hope this may clear you.

Comment: @Dipu - -63 is represented as `FFFFFFC1`, whne you perform the AND operation, you get `FFFFFFC1 & 0x0000001f == 0x00000001` that's the clculation. the representation of the number -63, is as two's complement.

Comment: @Dipu: I explicitly showed that in the answer: the spec says that "it is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator with the mask value 0x1f" and then took that and applied it to your example: `-63 & 0x1f` is 1.

Comment: @JonSkeet what if the left operand is of type float or double?

Answer (score 5):

`s = s >>-63;` is like  `s = s >> 1;` (-63 % 32)

Take a look at the [shift operator behavior](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19) at the JLS §15.19.

Answer (score 2):

The following 2 statements are producing one and the same result for integers if you want to replace negative shift:

```
r << -shift
```

and

```
r << ((32 - shift) % 32)
```

(32 is the size of integer in Java)

Answer (score 1):

```
    int s＝8；        
    Assert.assertEquals(s >>-63, s >>-63 % 32);
    Assert.assertEquals(s >>-63, s >>-31);
    Assert.assertEquals(s >>-31, s >>32 -31);
    Assert.assertEquals(s >>32 -31，s >>1); 
    Assert.assertEquals(s >>1，s ／2); 
    Assert.assertEquals(s/2，4);
```

Answer (score 1):

Shifting with -63 actually shifts with `-63 & 0x1f == 1` for int or `-63 & 0x3f == 1` for long, because in Java shifting left with `>>` uses sign-extension, and 1 will shift out any zero bits in the case of 8.